# OAuth authentication in API to connect to ETSY

Tags: php, api, oauth, web-hosting

I am trying to create an API to connect to ETSY and obtain orders information. They require authentication with OAuth.

I am looking for a script that can do the OAuth step relying on an external library, and not on a pre-installed server package, as ipage.com (my current host) does not have the OAuth package installed.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? What is the expected result?

Comment: I am just running the code and according to the manual from ETSY "The response will contain your temporary credentials, including a field called login_url with a URL..." https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/oauth#perm_scope_transactions_r

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you got that code from exactly, but the correct class you want to instantiate is `\OAuth\OAuth1\Service\Etsy`. Each service in the library has its own class.

You don't have to look at the individual implementations for connecting users with your app. We already have abstracted that part for you. The easiest way to get you started with the Etsy service is to copy [the example](https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib/blob/master/examples/etsy.php).

You can add your key and secret [here](https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib/blob/master/examples/etsy.php#L27).

Once the user has approved your app you can start making requests to the service. An example of this can be found [here](https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib/blob/master/examples/etsy.php#L47).

From that point on you can simply make requests by doing `$etsyService->request('/whatever/you/want/to/get')` by choosing the correct path from http://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation.

Comment: When running the https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib/blob/master/examples/etsy.php I get nothing, just errors....

Comment: Error: "Fatal error: "Call to a member function getAbsoluteUri() on a non-objec...t"

Answer (score 0):

Probably because etsy did not return a `login_url`

First, try `print_r($req_token)` - see if that provides anything useful (like an error message)

Failing that, if `$req_token` is false, you may want to see if your SSL libraries are up to par. Try a `phpinfo();` and check the PHP error log to see if either (1) SSL is not supported for your PHP install or (2) there is an error with the SSL connection.

Comment: You need to add Oauth PECL package to you php library.